# gomock, Go,mango package ,MongoMock

Tags: go, gomock, mongomock

I am trying to mock the below method using gomock

```
func GetS(tenantName string) (*mgo.Session, error) {
    ctx := apiContext.TContext{}
    url, err := connectionURLList.get(tenantName)
    if err != nil {
        log.GenericWarning(ctx,
            fmt.Sprintf("connection to %s not yet created, creating one: %v", tenantName, err), nil)
        if err := connectMongo(tenantName); err == nil {
            return GetS(tenantName) //singleton recursion to again call GetS
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    // ignoring error, expected we will always setting session in session map
    session, _ := connectionList.get(url)
    return session.Copy(), err
}
```

My Interface

```
type MongoManager interface {
    GetS(tenantName string) 
}

func TestGetS(t *testing.T) {
    //var mgoCall *mgo.Session
    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer mockCtrl.Finish()
    mockManagerObj := mocks.NewMockMongoManager(mockCtrl)
    mockManagerObj.EXPECT().GetS("cacargroup").Return(nil)
}
```

I am Getting the below error . Can someone help

```
 $ go test
```

> --- FAIL: TestGetS (0.00s)
>           mongoManager_test.go:20: missing call(s) to *mocks.MockMongoManager.GetS(is equal to cacargroup) /Users/charles/workspace/src/bitbucket.org/tekion/tbaas/mongoManager/mongoManager_test.go:16
>           mongoManager_test.go:20: aborting test due to missing call(s) FAIL exit status 1

Comment: From your test it seems like you not called any method/function which would execute `GetS` method before you expected it to be called.

Comment: `func TestGetS(t *testing.T) {

 //var mgoCall *mgo.Session
 mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
 defer mockCtrl.Finish()
 mockManagerObj := mocks.NewMockMongoManager(mockCtrl)
 _ , err := GetS("cacargroup")
 if err != nil {
  t.Errorf("session is not generated")
 }
 mockManagerObj.EXPECT().GetS("cacargroup").Return(nil)



}`

Comment: Still getting the same error `--- FAIL: TestGetS (0.00s)
        mongoManager_test.go:24: missing call(s) to *mocks.MockMongoManager.GetS(is equal to cacargroup) /Users/charles/workspace/src/bitbucket.org/tekion/tbaas/mongoManager/mongoManager_test.go:20
        mongoManager_test.go:24: aborting test due to missing call(s)
FAIL
exit status 1
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see actually the method in your interface implemented with return type of an error. But you are using like it returns nothing and chaining the implementation. Just remove the return type of `GetS`.

```
type fn func(string) (*mgo.Session, error)

type MongoManager interface {
    NewFunction(GetS, "cascade")
}

func TestGetS(t *testing.T) {
    //var mgoCall *mgo.Session
    mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer mockCtrl.Finish()
    mockManagerObj := mocks.NewMockMongoManager(mockCtrl)
    mockManagerObj.EXPECT().GetS("cacargroup").Return(nil)
}
```

Also you have to remove it from `GetS` function too

```
func NewFunction(GetS fn, value string){
   GetS("cascade")
}

func GetS(tenantName string) (*mgo.Session, error){
    ctx := apiContext.TContext{}
    url, err := connectionURLList.get(tenantName)
    if err != nil {
        log.GenericWarning(ctx,
            fmt.Sprintf("connection to %s not yet created, creating one: %v", tenantName, err), nil)
        if err := connectMongo(tenantName); err == nil {
            return GetS(tenantName) //singleton recursion to again call GetS
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    // ignoring error, expected we will always setting session in session map
    session, _ := connectionList.get(url)
}
```

Comment: ```func TestGetS(t *testing.T) {
 //var mgoCall *mgo.Session
 mockCtrl := gomock.NewController(t)
 defer mockCtrl.Finish()
 mockManagerObj := mocks.NewMockMongoManager(mockCtrl)
 mockManagerObj.EXPECT().GetS("cacargroup").Return(nil)
}```

Comment: post the interface and modify your main post not in comments

Comment: ```type MongoManager interface {
 GetS(tenantName string)

}```